# Android Studio never finishes uploading app to the Nexus 10

Tags: android, debugging, upload, android-studio

I have a Nexus 10 and i decided to start learning Android. I installed Android Studio, turned the USB Debugging on and it shows in the Android Studio, but when I try to debug an app, it says:

```
    Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-nexus_10-R32D100GNFL
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Kamen\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationProject\MyApplication\build\apk\MyApplication-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.some.myapplication
```

It never finishes the upload, just stays this way for hours and hours.

When I try the same with my Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, it starts debugging right away.

Please help :)

Comment: If my answer about the USB cables doesn't help (it's pretty easy to try and is worth a shot), then please attach the output from adb logcat while trying to upload to the N10.

Comment: I have the same problem. It installed several times successfully, but now it never finishes uploading file. I tried different cable, different usb-ports, uncheck an recheck usb-debugging, deinstalling previous tests, rebooting, cleaning. Other device does work. Strange. What else can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Try one or two other different USB cables. We see this problem happen a lot and a different cable sometimes helps. I'm not entirely sure why this is; different devices have different USB hardware and software and can sometimes be surprisingly picky.

Comment: I will try a different USB cable and later tell you if its working or not. Maybe the problem is that I use the same USB cable for the Nexus and the Galaxy Ace 2, but I clearly remember using the same cable with the ADT bundle, and it worked perfectly. Will inform on the results later, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: It's a bit of a longshot, but it's a quick thing to check. If that doesn't work, let me know. A memory stirs that the N10 has been problematic with ADB.

Comment: Amazing... I wouldn't have believed it - but a different cable and it works(!) Everything looked OK, I could see the event on the device, both ends knew the debugger was running - but it got do downdload and just never got to install... changed the cable... zap it works...